# ios ,iTunes file sharing save audio file

Tags: ios, load, save, nsdictionary, file-sharing

i try to record the voice file in aac type 
and show in uitable and work good but  i can not showing in itunes file sharing

I activated the **UIFIleSharingEnabled**

but i can not look the aac file in itunes file sharing   what can i do ?

file format **AudioformatMPEG4AAC**

fileaddres  : file://localhost/Users/myuser/..**.aac**

Save part

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"voicestr",,@"datestr",@"durstr",nil];

NSDictionary * HistDict =[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myString,timeString,dateString,currentimeLbl.text,bestsize ,nil] forKeys:keys];

[Hist addObject:HistDict];
```

load file

```
 BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath];if (fileExists) 
    HistValue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
```

Comment: The file must be stored in the `Documents` directory.

Comment: ok
if you can help me for stored in documet directory with this code ?
for AAC file

Comment: Do a search on `NSDocumentDirectory`. You'll find plenty of samples.

Comment: if only save in nsDocumentdirectory ints automaticaly read in itunes file sharing ?

Comment: Yes, iTunes file sharing shows the contents of the app's Documents directory.

Comment: thanks man 
if is only 2 or 3 line code is there possible to help me because i am very amator to this

Answer (score 1):

You get the document directory for iOS with this method:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *basePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]
```

Add the File name

```
NSString *fielWithPath = [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileNaem"];
```

And you have to enable file sharing in the `info.plist`

```
UIFileSharingEnabled = YES
```